# Test class Unit test not covering method

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image]I have a method

**Controller**

```
public PageReference selectBandwidth() {

  if (!BandwidthQualified
        || prequalToSave == null
        || servicesToAdd == null
        || (prequalToSave != null && prequalToSave.IsComplete__c && servicesToAdd.size() == 0))
    {
        return Page.PBXOrderingQuotePdf;
    }

    Decimal bandServicesSel = 0;

    if (servicesToAdd != null)
    {
        for (Service__c service : servicesToAdd)
        {
            if (service.IsSelected__c)
                bandServicesSel += 1;
        }
    }

        showPageMessage = false;
        pageMessage = '';

    if (!String.isBlank(qotId)) { 
        qot = [select Id, Pricebook2Id, Name from Quote where Id = :qotId];

    }
    else if (!isVoiceBeingAdded)
    {
        if (qot.Name == null)
            qot.Name = 'No Name';
        qot.BillingCity = city;
        qot.BillingState = state ;
        qot.BillingPostalCode = zip ;

        qot.BillingStreet = addressLine1 + ' ' + unitType + ' ' + unitValue ;
        qot.ShippingCity =  account.ShippingCity; 
        qot.ShippingCountry = account.ShippingCountry;
        qot.ShippingStreet = account.ShippingStreet;
        qot.ShippingState = account.ShippingState;
        qot.ShippingPostalCode = account.ShippingPostalCode;
        insert qot;
        url = '/apex/QuotePDF?id=' + qot.Id;
    }

    List<PricebookEntry> products = [Select Id, ProductCode , IsActive, Product2Id, UnitPrice, Name 
                                    from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =: qot.Pricebook2Id];

    if (servicesToAdd != null)
    {
        System.debug('I am inside the Service and service has been added 1');
        for (Service__c service : servicesToAdd)
        {
             System.debug('I am inside the Service and service has been added 2' + servicesToAdd );
            if (service.IsSelected__c)
            {
                 System.debug('I am inside the Service and service has been added 3 service.IsSelected__c' );

                for (PricebookEntry entry : products)
                {
                    System.debug('entry.ProductCode Counter' + entry.ProductCode);
                    if (entry.ProductCode == 'internetAccessWizard')
                    {
                        QuoteLineItem quoteLineItem = new QuoteLineItem();
                        quoteLineItem.QuoteId = qot.Id;
                        quoteLineItem.PricebookEntryId = entry.Id;
                        quoteLineItem.Product2Id = entry.Product2Id;
                        quoteLineItem.Quantity = 1;
                        quoteLineItem.UnitPrice = service.Price__c;
                                                   quoteLineItem.Enter_Activation__c = service.SetupPrice__c;
                        quoteLineItem.Activation_Fee_CheckBox__c = true;
                        quoteLineItem.Term_Area__c = service.ContractLength__c;
                        System.debug(' Contract Term ' +  quoteLineItem.Term_Area__c );

                        if(service.SubType__c.contains('test')){
                            quoteLineItem.Internet_Service_Fee__c = 2.88;
                            quoteLineItem.Internet_Service_Fee_CheckBox__c = true;
                        }
                        else{

                            quoteLineItem.It_HAS_FSLS_checkBox__c = true;
                        }
                        insert quoteLineItem;
                    }
                }
                bandServicesSel += 1;
            }
        }
    }
   return Page.PBXOrderingQuotePdf;
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
static testmethod void selectBandwidth_Test(){
    OpportunityController controller = new OpportunityController();
    controller.BandwidthQualified = false;

    Product2 prod = new Product2();
    prod.Name = 'Laptop X200'; 
    prod.IsActive = true;
    prod.ProductCode  = 'Feature';

    insert prod;

    id customPB = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name = 'Test';
    opp.StageName='Quote Sent';
    opp.CloseDate = system.today();
    opp.Pricebook2Id = customPB;
    insert opp;

    Quote quote = new Quote();
    quote.Name='test';
    quote.Opportunityid = opp.id;     
    quote.ExpirationDate = date.today()+30;        
    quote.Pricebook2Id = customPB;

    //insert quote;

    controller.isVoiceBeingAdded = false;

    PricebookEntry customPrice = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = customPB, Product2Id = prod.Id,
        UnitPrice = 12000, IsActive = true);

    insert customPrice;

    controller.qot = quote;
    controller.selectBandwidth();
 }
```

I am not sure what else to add

Comment: You should probably start by adding assertions. Code coverage is *not* the chief goal in writing unit tests. Your primary aim should be to **[verify application behavior using assertions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct)**. If you have not written any assertions, you have not written a *unit test*. You have written a *smoke test*.

Comment: @Eric 0 percent is covering

Comment: @Eric When i Run it with Mavenmate Desktop App, even (bandServicesSel = 0;) red  its all red

Comment: @Eric I added a screen shot

Comment: @Eric its not showing me any error in here. I am not sure what I am suppose to look for, or else I wouldnt have asked for help

Comment: Someone will have to tell you were the error is shown in MM as I have not used it for over a year. but the results of the test would have presented an error message. To get you moving again I'll post an answer that will get you past this point but not solve your code issues. Suggest you visit trailhead and go through the Apex and testing modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me following things to be incorporated:

- From test method you have not created any records to cover this logic.

  ```
  if (!BandwidthQualified
          || prequalToSave == null
          || servicesToAdd == null
          || (prequalToSave != null && prequalToSave.IsComplete__c && servicesToAdd.size() == 0))
      {
          return Page.PBXOrderingQuotePdf;
      }
  ```
- All the above conditions must not to be satisfied if you want to proceed with next steps.

  Your test method doesnot have data to satisfy `servicesToAdd!=null)` and you have not created any records for `Service__c`.

  ```
  if (servicesToAdd != null)
  {
      for (Service__c service : servicesToAdd)
      {
          if (service.IsSelected__c)
              bandServicesSel += 1;
      }
  }
  ```
- You have to create products with `ProductCode = 'internetAccessWizard'` so that following block to be statisfied.

  ```
  if (entry.ProductCode == 'internetAccessWizard')
  ```

This is way, you should cover each logic.

Comment: hey at   if(service.SubType__c.contains('ATTIPBROADBAND') ){  now unit test gives an error System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Stack Trace

Comment: nvm got it and fixed it

Answer (score 2):

When working with Boolean values and using the `!` operator you are dereferencing the property. If the boolean is null you will get a Dereference Null Pointer Exception.

In your image it is clear (once you understand how to read the coverage data) that this line is causing an error because everything after it is uncovered, even lines not inside code blocks:

```
if (!BandwidthQualified
```

Either ensure it is not null by setting a default value or do not dereference it and do this

```
if (BandwidthQualified == false
```

As an aside, this is one of the benefits of the format you are using by putting different criteria on separate lines. Had they all been on one line it would not be immediately clear which property was causing the issue